# "You're exaggerated" and "you're being exaggerated"

Tags: verb-usage

Do both of these sentences exist? Can I say *I'm being exaggerated*, or should I say *I'm exaggerated*? (I want to express that I'm overdoing something.)

Is either one wrong, or are they both correct?

Comment: Similar to "I am overdoing it", "I am exaggerating". What you are exaggerating is implied or in other context.

Answer (score 1):

Both are odd.

We might say that a person is exaggerating something when they speak.

> Fred said "My car's as big as a whale", but he was exaggerating.

It was the description of the car that Fred was exaggerating, not himself.

You could also say of a drawing that it has (for example) an exaggerated nose.

The thing that is exaggerated is a description or a representation of a real object. What is odd is to say that a real object is exaggerated. In particular, it is odd to say "I'm exaggerated".

If you want to say that you are overdoing something then say "I'm overdoing something." or say "I'm doing somthing too much/too often." Exaggerate is the wrong word in this context.

Comment: Is it possible that "I am exaggerated by somebody else." , meaning you are not good as you are being  described?

Comment: It means that their description of you is exaggerated. It would be better to say "He is exaggerating my abilities" for example.

Answer (score 0):

"Exaggerated" is an adjective used to describe something that has been presented in a way that is larger or more extreme than it actually is.  Normally you would focus on some characteristic, mannerism, or statement of that person, not the person himself:

> Everything about Trump, from his unruly hair, to his lavish lifestyle, to his impulsive midnight tweets, is **exaggerated** and perhaps deliberately unpredictable.

Trump often *exaggerates*, or we can say that claims against him are often *exaggerated*, but we would not normally say that that he himself is an *exaggerated person*, except perhaps figuratively.

Comment: As I asked @James K: 
Is it possible that "I am exaggerated by somebody else." , meaning you are not good as you are being described?

Comment: @dan  No, that's not natural.  Instead you would talk about some characteristic of yourself that has been exaggerated,  "My friend told you I am a genius with computers, but that might have been exaggerated.  I'm just a programmer."